# Invalid cast exception?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETVendorsStatsAgainstSearTerm]
    @Date DateTime , 
    @SearchId  bigint
AS

declare @cmd as varchar(2000)
set @cmd = ' select *, ' + cast(SearchId as varchar) + ' as SearhId   from tbl'
exec (@cmd)
```

I want to treat `SearchId` as a column to run the select query against. I want to know the correct type for the `SearchId` column.

I am unable to convert this `SearchId` column into a long data type in C#. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `cast(SearchId as varchar(50))` -- add length on the varchar or else it will be converted as `VARCHAR(1)`.

Comment: @JW Not exactly, in CAST and CONVERT functions the default is VARCHAR(30) not 1, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Comment: @TwoMore : It may or may not assign the desired length which you are expecting.It can `truncate` the value . Check this article from Aaron  https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: @JW This article you linked says exactly what i say, even with the example where using cast the default is 30 not 1

Comment: @TwoMore well I can't argue with that since it from msdn docs but my basis of my answer is from the link given by praveen. It says there: `The problem is, if you don't define a length, SQL Server will assign one for you, and it may not be as wide as you expect.  In some scenarios, it will be 1 (yes, that is the number one, not a typo), and in others it will be 30.` [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3240)

Comment: @JW I'm not saying anything else, what i saied is when CAST or CONVERT are involved then the default value assigned by SQL Server to a varchar is 30, that implies when there are no CAST or CONVERT involved (result 1 in your fiddle) the default value ist not 30 (it's 1 in this case which is) and that is exactly result 2 in the Fiddle you attached, we mean the same thing at the end i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Convert function`

```
Convert(varchar(50),SearchId )
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that there are some unassigned SearchId's which causes csating a null into varchar.

Try something like this:

```
//...
set @cmd = CASE
   WHEN (SearchId IS NOT NULL) THEN (' select *, ' + cast(SearchId as varchar) + ' as SearhId from tbl')
   ELSE ' select *, 0 as SearhId from tbl'
END
///...
```

Comment: how can you explain this? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3240 basically the server I used is `SQL Server 2012`.